A question about the equation $x dy + y dx = d(xy)$
I am trying to solve a DE
$$xy -1 + (x^2 - xy) y' = 0$$
and the solution given by the textbook is:
First, rewrite the DE as
$$(xy -1)dx + (x^2 - xy) dy = 0$$
Then, divide it by $x$, we have
$$y dx - \frac{1}{x} dx + x dy - y dy = 0$$
and this implies
$$ x dy + y dx - \frac{1}{x} dx - y dy = 0$$
But here, the textbook claims that we have
$$x dy + y dx = d(xy) \cdots (*)$$
and so plugs $(*)$ into the DE.
$\textbf{Question:}$ Why do we have $(*)$ and what is the mathematical meaning behind it? Can someone help explain it and tell me how to study it more deeply? Thanks!

This is just the product rule of derivative:
$$
    \dfrac{d}{dx}(xy) = y + x \dfrac{dy}{dx}
$$
or, in differential form: $d(xy) = ydx + xdy$. Note that, here $y$ is a function of $x$, i.e $y = y(x)$

Thanks for your help! I now understand it.
